# RouterLink is appending object info on the route

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner with angular an dI'm trying to use `RouterLink` to generate a link

this is the route:

```
{ path: 'heroe/:id', component: HeroeComponent},
```

and this is the html

```
<h1>Heroes <small>de Marvel y DC</small></h1>
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card animated fadeIn fast" *ngFor="let heroe of heroes; let i of index">
        <img [src]="heroe.img" class="card-img-top" [alt]="heroe.nombre">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ heroe.nombre }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ heroe.bio }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ heroe.aparicion }}</small></p>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
                Ver más...
            </button>-->
            <a [routerLink]="['/heroe',i]" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Ver más...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but its creating a route appendign all the `heroe` object on the url , like:

```
http://localhost:4200/heroe;nombre=Aquaman;bio=El%20poder%20m%C3%A1s%20reconocido%20de%20Aquaman%20es%20la%20capacidad%20telep%C3%A1tica%20para%20comunicarse%20con%20la%20vida%20marina,%20la%20cual%20puede%20convocar%20a%20grandes%20distancias.;img=assets%2Fimg%2Faquaman.png;aparicion=1941-11-01;casa=DC
```

Comment: what is `i`? provide a reproduction of your issue

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i  its the index  of the array element

Comment: The correct syntax is `let heroe of heroes; index as i`

Comment: Please check https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables and align your template syntax with the example